# Find all paths in a directed graph that pass a single node (NetworkX)

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory, graph-traversal

Let's assume I have this directed graph:

[image: Original Directed Graph]

What's the optimal (complexity and simplicity) way to get every path that passes through a given node?
Let's say I choose `node = 4` I want to get this sub-graph:

[image: Sub graph that passes a single node]
Currently I am using NetworkX python library, however I am open to choosing another one if it has this capability.

Comment: Is the graph always a DAG?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark yes it's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me propose an "ugly" solution (and I am sure there is a better way). First, find all descendants and ancestors of the node:

```
desc = nx.descendants(G, 4)
anc = nx.ancestors(G, 4)
```

Next, find the simple paths from each ancestor to the node and from the node to each descendant:

```
paths = [path for p in desc for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 4, p)]
paths.extend([path for p in anc for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, p, 4)])
```

Finally, reconstruct the digraph from the paths:

```
Q = nx.DiGraph()
for p in paths:
    nx.add_path(Q, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. As in the answer by DYZ, let `anc` denote the ancestors and `desc` denote the descendants of the chosen node. Let `nodes` = `anc` union `desc` union `{chosen_node}`. Iterate over edges `(i, j)` of the original graph, and delete an edge if either of the following holds:

- `i` or `j` are not in the set `nodes`.
- `i` is in `anc` and `j` is in `desc`.

A node `x not in nodes` cannot be on any path containing `chosen_node`, or else `x` would have to be an ancestor, a descendant, or `chosen_node` itself (condition 1). If `(i, j)` is a node from an ancestor `i` to descendant `j`, it cannot be on any path containing `chosen_node` because of the acyclic assumption (condition 2).

Every remaining edge is on some path containing the `chosen_node`. I believe you can prove it by induction on `min(distance(i, chosen_node), distance(j, chosen_node))`.

---

```
def remove_edges(G, node=0):
  desc = nx.descendants(G, node)
  anc = nx.ancestors(G, node)
  nodes = anc.union(desc).union({node})
  Q = nx.DiGraph()
  for i, j in G.edges:
    # remove edges with either source or target not in nodes
    if (i not in nodes) or (j not in nodes):
      continue
    # remove edges immediately connecting ancestors to descendants
    if (i in anc) and (j in desc):
      continue
    Q.add_edge(i,j)
  return Q
```

Comment: Your solution would also include a two-edge path that starts, say, at 10 and ends at 6, but does not go through 4.

Comment: Do you have a small example to show this? In OP's picture, the only such path is 10 -> 11 -> 6, and will be excluded because edges containing 11 are filtered out by the first condition.

Comment: I tested my solution against yours on random graphs using generator from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543069/how-to-create-random-single-source-random-acyclic-directed-graphs-with-negative), but maybe I missed some special cases.

Comment: Just add another path from 10 to 6 through a new node 15: 10->15->6.

Comment: That wouldn't cause a problem either as 15 will be neither ancestor or descendant of 4, so all edges containing 15 will be filtered out.

Comment: Yes, probably true.