# How can I create random DAG graphs, where nodes has only single direction, in Python

Tags: python, random, graph, networkx

I want to generate random `DAG`s, where all node connections be only single direction.

I have tried following solution [How can I create random single source random acyclic directed graphs with negative edge weights in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13546785/2402577), which is able to generate random `DAG`s but node connections can be two way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a **directed graph without cycles**.

My favorite Python package for directed graphs is `networkx`.

Here is a example of random directed DAG generation:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def generate_random_dag(num_nodes, num_edges):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    while G.number_of_edges() < num_edges:
        G.add_edge(*random.sample(range(num_nodes), 2))
        if not nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G):
            G.remove_edges_from(list(nx.find_cycle(G, orientation='original')))
    return G

G = generate_random_dag(10, 15)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Note the use of the class `DiGraph` (`Di` for directed), instead of `Graph` or other options.

Giving you this output:

[image: Directed graph output]

Following-up here with the question from comments: in essence, *can we enforce a specific node (like #0) to be the initial node?*

Here is the modified code to do that (for node 0 in this example but number can easily be changed to any other node):

```
def generate_random_dag(num_nodes, num_edges):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    while G.number_of_edges() < num_edges:
        start_node, end_node = random.sample(range(num_nodes), 2)
        # ensure that node 0 is always a source (initial node)
        if end_node == 0:  
            start_node, end_node = end_node, start_node
        G.add_edge(start_node, end_node)
        if not nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G):
            G.remove_edge(start_node, end_node)
    return G

G = generate_random_dag(10, 15)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

which gives you the following output graph (note that node 0 does not have any incoming edges, as expected):

[image: Output DAG with node 0 as initial node]

Following-up with the second question from the comments: *can we enforce a specific node (like #0) to be the initial node AND make sure that the graph has a unique source node?*

Here is the modified code to do that:

```
def generate_random_dag(num_nodes, num_edges):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    
    for node in range(1, num_nodes):
        G.add_edge(0, node)

    while G.number_of_edges() < num_edges:
        start_node, end_node = random.sample(range(num_nodes), 2)
        # only node 0 as source, no other sources
        if end_node == 0 or start_node == 0:  
            continue
        G.add_edge(start_node, end_node)
        if not nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G):
            G.remove_edge(start_node, end_node)
    return G

G = generate_random_dag(10, 15)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

And the resulting graph output:

[image: Resulting graph with node 0 as UNIQUE source]

Comment: Is it possible to always set `node 0` as sink (initial) node, where it does not receive any input?

Comment: no, node 0 is not always a sink, intermediate or source node. the graph (from code above) is constructed by randomly adding edges between node pairs. The role of any node (as a source, sink, or intermediate node) is not explicitly defined and entirely depends on the outcome of this random process.

Comment: to answer your second question, yes, we definitely could force a specific role for node 0. I need to change the code accordingly, coming back to you shortly..

Comment: Just a clarification first: you need node 0 as sink or source? My understanding of the definition of sink is a node with no outgoing edges, which would be the "final" one and source -a node with no incoming edges, which could be called "initial". which one do you need for node 0?

Comment: I wanted node-0 as an initial node, a node with no incoming edges.

Comment: If possible only a single node (like if there is 10 nodes number 9) could be sink node.

Comment: I have added a proposed solution at the end of the initial answer. Pls let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yes, its perfect! If possible, could only a single node (like if there is 10 nodes number 9) be a sink node? I can try to figure out from your code.

Comment: sure, let me see how to adjust it accordingly..

Comment: here you go. I have added this new variant at the end of the answer. let me know if this is what you wanted

Comment: I have tried your solution with 160 nodes and 160 edges seems like it does not create exact number of the given node, like it creates much less

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

def random_dag(nodes, edges):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    for i in range(nodes):
        G.add_node(i)
    while edges > 0:
        a = random.randint(0, nodes-1)
        b = a
        while b == a:
            b = random.randint(0, nodes-1)
        G.add_edge(a, b)
        if nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G):
            edges -= 1
        else:
            G.remove_edge(a, b)
    return G

G = random_dag(5, 4)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: Will there be edge for all the nodes? Like for example when we call `random_dag(100, 100)`, could there be nodes without any edge?